# Looking for a short story about a man who made mouse traps

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

Many years ago I heard on the radio a story about a man who lived in a village where there was a rat infestation. He decides to make a rat trap and it is so good his friends ask for one. Then the village then the area etc. As his business grows he employs many people like sales, accounts, HR, managers etc etc but there is still only him making the rat traps almost 24/7. His life is a misery and he regrets inventing the rat trap while his company employees enjoy 9 to 5 jobs with good salaries. A great story for today when some businesses are just like this.

I think the story was read by Earl Nightingale although it may not have been written by him, I may be wrong though as it was at least 40 years ago. Over the past 10 years I have searched the internet but as yet not found this one. I have found many stories of rat traps and rat infestations, I even searched YouTube and found many there but not the one I was looking for. Then I came across this site today.

Comment: If you have a list of stories which are close but definitely not what you're looking for, please do tell us - saves others some time.

Comment: "Man Who Builds Better Mousetrap Caught In Rat Race" Not an actual title, but what I thought when I read that.

Comment: Do you remember what radio station you were listening to? I know NPR has had a number of interesting bits of fiction.